# Message Queueing broken - Configuration MMC is missing now too

Tags: windows-server-2003, configuration, msmq, message-queuing

Help!  I have a Windows Server 2003 partition that was running yesterday with no problems.  It has the message queueing component installed, and I had four private message queues in it.

I did some work with attaching and detaching SQL Server 2005 databases yesterday and restarted the server today.

Now, under Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Services and Applications, Message Queuing no longer shows up.

Additionally, if I try to stop or restart the Message Queuing service, I get the error "The service did not respond in a timely fashion", and then it's stuck on "Stopping" indefinitely.

The applications that rely on the message queues are broken, saying that they can't write to the queues.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling and re-installing Message Queuing in Add/Remove programs -> Add/Remove Windows Components seems to have done the trick.

Now I have to recreate the message queues though.

Comment: This is happening to me regularly on windows 2008 server. If the box crashes or for any reason rebooted ungracefully, the msmq service corrupts and fails to start. reinstall is all that helps.
For anyone else who gets this, sometimes the uninstall wont work and you need to

net stop wuauserv
net stop bits
Delete “%windir%\softwaredistribution”
reboot and uninstall should work